# How to pass externals from webpack to jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, webpack, jestjs

I've got this webpack config as part of my grunt building process:

```
module.exports = {
options: {
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('../ui/static/js'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[name].js',
        libraryTarget: 'amd',
        library: '[name]'
    },

    externals: [
        'jquery',
        'lodash',
        'backbone',
        'backbone.layoutmanager',
        'moment',
        'spin',
        'lib/select2.min',
        'dispatcher'
    ],
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve('../ui'),
        alias: {
            'jst': 'static/jst'
        }
    }
```

We are moving to react now, and I need to import some files in my test files, where this dependencies included, but jest can not find them:

```
Cannot find module 'lib/select2.min' from 'helpers.js'
Cannot find module 'jst/templates_jst' from 'base-view.js
```

What is the right way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using a setup file and importing those packages and attaching to `global`?

Comment: Yep. It fails on my templates, which included in webpack like this:
    `resolve: {
            root: path.resolve('../ui'),
            alias: {
                'jst': 'static/jst'
            }
        }`
And i get this on jest: `Cannot find module 'jst/templates_jst' from 'base-view.js'`

Comment: I can prevent errors with spin, jquery, backbone by adding them to `__mocks__` folder, but I can't realise how to deal with `jst/templates_jst`

Comment: one more possibility is to use virtual mock
`jest.mock('jst/templates_jst', () => {}, {virtual: true})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what works today with `webpack@4.11.1` and `jest@23.1.0`. Assuming this is your externals webpack config:

```
externals: {
  react: {
    root: 'React',
    commonjs2: 'react',
    commonjs: 'react',
    amd: 'react',
  },
}
```

You'll need to map each external library to be properly resolved in your jest config like so:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  "^./react": path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react'),
}
```

While debugging your issue, be sure to check what your built component file looks like. You want to be sure that you see something like:

```
!function(e,t){if("object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof module)
module.exports=t(require("react"));
else if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd)define(["react"],t);
else{var n="object"==typeof exports?t(require("react")):t(e.React);
```

Important bit being `react` for commonjs and amd, and `React` for the browser.

Answer (score 3):

You need to **mock** the external lib.

Example with jquery:

1. Create a __mocks__ folder in the same level of __test__ folder.
2. Inside that, create a file with the same name of the dependency, in this case, jquery (jquery.js).
3. Inside the test file, use *jest.mock* function to reference the mock external dependency: jest.mock('jquery');

from jest the docs:
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/manual-mocks.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: How would this solve the issue? If I mock react in my tests they'll no longer pass, since I need actual react to render the components for tests.

Comment: for react it won't help of course, in case of react as external lib, you must have it in dependencies anyway. But it works great for some external packages that doesn't affect your tests, but still have to be installed just to resolve imports and compile things. Here mocks fit well.

Answer (score 2):

For my case using the `__mocks__` would be a bit verbose but I used the

```
jest.mock('myModule', () => {/* module impl */}, {virtual: true})
```

In case the `__mocks__` suggestion is to verbose for you too check out the docs [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#:%7E:text=The%20third%20argument%20can%20be%20used%20to%20create%20virtual%20mocks%20%E2%80%93%20mocks%20of%20modules%20that%20don%27t%20exist%20anywhere%20in%20the%20system%3A)

Comment: this is awesome, I didn't see this mentioned in any of my web searches I performed and this works so good for external libraries that I also didn't want to be so verbose in creating, thank you

Comment: Excellent answer. Didn't know of this {virtual: true}. It works to me like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use moduleNameMapper but simply stub it with jest-transform-stub, if you don't need the functionality.